Restricting OAuth2 Endpoints to Specific Authorities in Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server
I'm working with a Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server to secure my application's endpoints. My goal is to restrict OAuth2 related endpoints (e.g., /oauth2/authorize, /oauth2/token) to users with the OAUTH2 authority, while allowing application endpoints accessible to users with the USER authority.
Current Configuration:
Here's a breakdown of my relevant security filter chains:
@Bean
@Order(1)
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
  http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(withDefaults());
  http.oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()));
  http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
      new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), createRequestMatcher())); 
  return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .requestMatchers("/login", "/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").hasAuthority("OAUTH2") 
        .anyRequest().hasAuthority("USER") 
    )
    .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());  
  return http.build();
}

Application endpoints are working as expected - USER authority is required for general access. However, the OAuth2 endpoints (/oauth2/authorize, /oauth2/token) are accessible by users with any/empty authorities, rather than being restricted to the OAUTH2 authority.
How can I ensure that my OAuth2 secured endpoints are only accessible to users specifically possessing the OAUTH2 authority using Spring OAuth2 Authorization Server? I'd appreciate any assistance or insight.

Have you tried with     .anyRequest().authenticated()) ?

Or Use two seperate structure of urls and filter them.
requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").hasAuthority("OAUTH2")     requestMatchers("/user-or-public /**").hasAuthority("USER")     .anyRequest().authenticated())

@SohailAnwar both solutions didn't resolve
